# how to find out "parent window reload completion", from popup window?

Tags: javascript

I have to call jquery in the parent window after reload completes,so i need this ans...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. in parent window, you write this code

`<script>
window.open('child.html','child','width=800,height=640');
</script>`

Don't forget to add your code in your parent window too

`<script>
function doWhatYouWant() { alert('hi!'); }
</script>`

2. in child window, you just add this code

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.opener.doWhatYouWant();
});
</script>`

Is that like you want?

Comment: i want to know the parent window reloading completion status when i reloading it from a popup window. I am able to call as you said here, but i want to call it after parent window reloads,for that i need help...

Comment: can you do like below:

in window.opener.doWhatYouWant() change to

$(window.opener).ready(function() {
window.opener.doWhatYouWant();
});

"ready" refer to jQuery documentation, http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-document-ready-initialization/ or http://think2loud.com/jquery-document-ready-howto/